# How to display XPS document using a selected combobox item

Tags: vb.net

I am very new to programming, so please forgive me if this question seems so basic.  I have developed my first application - an xps viewer.  What I want to achieve is to be able to allow the user to select which document to open from a range of options that I have predefined in a combo box.

I've searched all over the net and can't find an article that shows me how to do this.  MSDN is bit too cryptic for me at this moment, so I get confused. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

PS>  I think I'm using the FixedDocumentViewer (hope I wrote it right). Thanks.

Kismet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that this is a WPF application, you would add a button to your form and add a Click event to that button (select the button in the designer, show the Properties, select the Events tab in the Properties, and double-click in the empty column on the Click line).

Also assuming that the combobox contains the name of the file to show the user, the button click event would look something like:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        Dim sFileName As String

        sFileName = DirectCast(ComboBox1.SelectedValue, String)
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(sFileName) Then
            Dim theDocument As New System.Windows.Xps.Packaging.XpsDocument(sFileName, System.IO.FileAccess.Read)

            documentViewer1.Document = theDocument.GetFixedDocumentSequence()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Exception: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks COMPETENT_TECH.  I just got in from work and I'm gonna give the code a try - hope it works.  I really want to learn programming, so I might come back and ask you to explain what you did exactly with this code.

Comment: Okay, so I tried the code and got the following exception:

"Type System.Windows.Xps.Packaging.XpsDocument is not defined"

Should I be putting a USING or IMPORTS statement in my code?  Your response would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Okay so I did some searching around and finally found that I was getting the exception because I hadn't added the REACHFRAMEWORK dll to my project.  So I did that, and the code works fine.

Now the problem is how do I link the ComboboxItem to a specific XPS document so that the path info is passed to the code?  I'm gonna do some research on this, but your help would be appreciated as well.  Thanks again.

Comment: @KismetAgbasi: The answer to the combobox issue is going to depend on how you are loading it. Your best bet is probably to mark this answer as answered by checking the checkmark next to the answer then open a new question for the combobox issue. When you open the question, you should include the code that you use to populate the combobox along with information on where the documents are stored that you need to access.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to do as you asked.