# Opening an xps file in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, xps

I have an xps document and want to open this in vb.net for viewing

I have googeled a lot but cant find somthing recognisable (working)

how can i open a xps file with vb.net?

Comment: Use the [Xps Document Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.xps.packaging.xpsdocument.aspx). Also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636128/how-to-display-xps-document-using-a-selected-combobox-item

Answer (score 1):

As said [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/255616/xps-file-create-open-print-in-asp-net-using-Csharp):

> It would also be good if you shared what you have done so far so that you can narrow your question to something specific...this is such a broad question and involves so much code people here will just wonder where to start from helping.
>
> Either way start off by knowing what XPS files are here:
>   http://blogote.com/ideas/how-to-ideas/what-is-xps-files-and-how-to-open-xps-file-extension/1367/
>
> Then dive into the 0s and 1s here:
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163664.aspx